# URL Rewrite Conditions & Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

----EDIT---

I have just realized that my explanation of the problem was missing an important piece of information.

The URL's should  **only**  be redirected if second parameter is present.

So the rule should read:

Redirect any URL that has /d/ in it, ONLY if /d2/ is *also* found in the URL.

----End Edit_*_*

I have the need to 301 redirect **all** URL's on a site that contain a specific parameter to the same URL, but with an additional directory included. All of the URL's that require redirection contain a certain directory: /d/ Example:

http://www.mysite.com/category1**/d/**subcategory1/subdirectory2/

--Should Redirect to --

http://www.mysite.com**/newdirectory/**category1**/d/**subcategory1/subdirectory2/

The one thing in common with any of the URLs' requiring redirection is that they all contain a directory /d/ in the URL, which always immediately follows the "category" directory as indicated in bold in sample URL's above. I would then like to insert an additional directory in front of the category directory as indicated in bold in the sample URL's above. The rest of the URL will remain the same.

Can anyone help with this?  I'm relatively new to mod_rewrite and realize I can make a big mess if I don't get it right.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can offer hlep

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (edited to reflect change in question):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/d/.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/d2/.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/newdirectory/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/d/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/newdirectory/$1/d/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Adiel, Thank you kindly for your reply. Unfortunately, my initial request for help had left out an important piece of information necessary to create the correct rule

Comment: I edited my answer. The redirect now only applies if the request contains both `/d/` and `/d2/`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file  in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the url contains a /d2/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /d2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+/d/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+/)$ /newdirectory/$1 [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Ulrich,Thank you kindly for your reply. Unfortunately, my initial request for help had left out an important piece of information necessary to create the correct rule.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, I managed to get it working :)  Again, a sincere thanks for your help!!!